# Unexpected Application Error! Cannot read properties of undefined reading length

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am developing an app using the CartProduct component and keep receiving an error stating that the length property is undefined. Is there something that I cant see? All feedback is greatly appreciated. These are the error codes I am receiving:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you post relevant part of the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.